# strange type inferring behaviour

Tags: java, generics, lambda, constructor-overloading, inferred-type

I have a very complex class that gets a generic value, a functional interface and some generic typed subclasses. Now I noticed some strange behaviour related to type inferring. Have a look at this code:

```
public class Test{
    public static class SubClass<F>{
        public SubClass(){}
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface FuncInterface {
        void operation(String s);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public <T> Test(T obj, FuncInterface fi, SubClass<T>...sc){}

    @SafeVarargs
    public <T> Test(T obj, SubClass<T>...sc){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test(
                    42,
                    (s)->{},
                    new SubClass<>());
    } 
}
```

The line Test t = new Test(...); cannot compile due to following error:

```
The constructor Test(int, (<no type> s) -> {}, new SubClass<>()) is undefined
```

Now I found two different possibilities to get this code working:
1) Set explicit type for the functional interface parameter

```
Test t = new Test(
    42,
    (String s)->{},
    new SubClass<>());
```

2) or remove the overloaded constructor.

```
/* public <T> Test(T obj, SubClass<T>...sc){} */
```

I really don't get the problem of the compiler here and why my solutions work. Can somebody please explain what is going on here.

Comment: Compiles fine for me with 1.8.0_65. You compiled with which javac version ?

Comment: Used 1.8.0_45 and just updated to 1.8.0_65 but still the same error.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse 4.4.0 and just noticed from command line it works. It seems to be an eclipse problem.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse has its own compiler, which has many problems with the new Java 8 features. Try to see if a similar bug has not been issued already. If not you can report it to the dev team. Personally, I switched to IntelliJ and I think it'll be definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's surely a problem of Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) which is used by Eclipse internally. To work-around it add argument type to the lambda:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test(
                42,
                (String s)->{},
                new SubClass<>());
}
```

This way it compiles fine (at least in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2).

Comment: Works with IntelliJ and command line. Correct Java. Bad bad eclipse. Thanks for help